# Output object attributes and values in alphabetical order

Tags: python, class, python-3.x

I need to generate an export (csv) of a series of simple objects like this:

```
class trx:
   def __init__(self,
                 file_name='',
                 bank='',
                 trans_type='',
                 account=''):

        self.filename = file_name
        self.bank = bank
        self.trans_type = trans_type
        self.account = account
```

What is the simplest way to list the attribute/value pairs in order by attribute? `__dict__` changes order every time.

Comment: You can use `collections.OrderedDict` and `sorted`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use `vars()` on `self`, then sort the items:

```
sorted(vars(self).items())
```

This then gives you a sorted list of `(attributename, value)` pairs.

However, if your class is little more than a container for 4 related datapoints, then consider using a [`namedtuple` class](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.namedtuple):

```
from collections import namedtuple

TRX = namedtuple('TRX', ('file_name', 'bank', 'trans_type', 'account'))
```

This lists the attributes in named order, always:

```
>>> from collections import namedtuple
>>> TRX = namedtuple('TRX', ('file_name', 'bank', 'trans_type', 'account'))
>>> TRX('foo.txt', 'Bar PLC', 'withdrawal', '1234xyz')
TRX(file_name='foo.txt', bank='Bar PLC', trans_type='withdrawal', account='1234xyz')
```

Because the instances are sequences (a subclass of `tuple` in fact) you can pass these directly to a [`csv.writer().writerow()` call](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html#csv.csvwriter.writerow); at the same time you can use `instance.bank` or `instance.file_name` to access the fields.

Another alternative is to use *dictionaries*, and use [`csv.DictWriter()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html#csv.DictWriter) to handle the order (the `fieldnames` argument determines the order).